# Why Nested curly braces in angular doesn't work?? What is alternative solution for it?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, expression, ng-style

I have a json object

```
"blog1":{ 
"blogid":"1", 
"body":"sometext"
  "IMG":"URL of image"
    }
```

I am trying to access this objects IMG element to set as background IMG for `div` using ng-style as below

```
<Div ng-controller="controller as ctrl">
       <div ng-style="background-image:URL('{{ctrl.object.blog{{ctrl.blogId}}.IMG}}');" >
```

My controller looks like (rough )

```
App.controller('controller', function (){
this.object= $firebaseObject();

this.blogId= $routeParams.blogId;

});
```

Notice that `div` with ng-style contains nested angular expression , and they do not evaluate. Is there any other solution to achieve this.

Note: this is single page application, so according to blog id in the URL ,I wanna display image . I'm using angular routing for SPA.

Comment: You don't have to use curly braces, you use [ ]. {{object.blog[blogId].IMG}}

Comment: I dnt have to mention ctrl.??

Comment: I don't know how you have your controller defined in the view. ng-controller="ctrl" ?

Comment: Yes , I hv defined it as controller as ctrl... The code not exactly same .U cn understand wht m say

Comment: Then your controller definition is wrong. If you have ng-controller="controller as ctrl" then your App.controller should match that name. But yes, you will have to put ctrl.whatever to print variables.

Comment: It is matching , controller name is same , that's what I'm telling   this is rough idea given about my controller in question.

Comment: I updated my answer, at the bottom you can find your case.

Comment: And wht if I use controller As

Comment: Thanks I'll try it tomorrow , if it work , I'l accept your answer. Thanks for your time buddy

Comment: If you are using controller As then you have to use that "as" in front of your variables. Look, whatever you do now to print variables, whether it is ctrl.var or simply var, do that but using another var as index ctrl.var[index] or var[index].

Comment: Thanks for your time , i did something tricky, I parsed the $firebaseObject() [Json format] in controller itself and extracted the specific property and assigned to variable and then I used that variable in HTML element. :) 

can i add you on facebook ? Please provide me email id

Comment: I dont have FB. I dunnot why you do such a thing. What you are trying to acchieve is basically this: http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/9405/

Answer (score 1):

To use a variable as index you do as follow

Controller:

```
$scope.myVar = 'something';
$scope.myObj = {something: {img: 'something else'}};
```

View:

```
{{myObj[myVar].img}}
```

In your case:

```
{{ctrl.object.blog[ctrl.blogId].IMG}}
```